# mapview and plot show different output for the same rasterLayer, why?

Tags: r, proj, wkt, mapview

Below is the `rasterLayer` RASTER_slope in a plot (4 `NA`s are shown in white):

[image]

Here is the metadata of RASTER_slope

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 4, 4, 16  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 500, 500  (x, y)
extent     : 2227000, 2229000, 1316500, 1318500  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=lcc +lat_0=12 +lon_0=-102 +lat_1=17.5 +lat_2=29.5 +x_0=2500000 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : values 
values     : -143.2145, 214.1981  (min, max)
```

Then I used `mapview` to get a dynamic visualization of RASTER_slope:

```
> mapview(RASTER_slope)
Warning messages:
1: In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO", prefer_proj = prefer_proj) :
Discarded ellps WGS 84 in Proj4 definition: +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +type=crs
2: In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO", prefer_proj = prefer_proj) :
Discarded datum World Geodetic System 1984 in Proj4 definition
3: In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO", prefer_proj = prefer_proj) :
Discarded ellps WGS 84 in Proj4 definition: +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +type=crs
4: In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO", prefer_proj = prefer_proj) :
Discarded datum World Geodetic System 1984 in Proj4 definition
```

The resulting `mapview` object looks like this:

[image]

The `mapview` object is displaying only 2 pixels with `NA`.

Probably I am wrong but I have the feeling that the key here is to pass a `crs` to RASTER_slope in a `WKT` format but I do not know how to do that.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to have an OpenStreetMap layer, this will always be in a spherical mercator projection.  So, your raster layer will be reprojected to this.  At the moment, this is being done automatically, with interpolation (hence different values).  If you want the values to remain at their original values without interpolation, perhaps you need to reproject yourself using nearest neighbor method, before plotting.

Answer (score 1):

Following @dww, the key is in adding `method="ngb"` when calling mapview, no need to re project the rasterLayer, though. Here the code and output

```
mapview(RASTER_slope, method="ngb", na.color="transparent")
```

[image]